# How to to convert point UV in image to XYZ in pointcloud2 (python)?

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given the pixel position, say (u,v) in the RGB image, how do I get the corresponding (X,Y,Z) from pointcloud2 data, using a sensor like kinetic camera.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276588/how-to-to-convert-point-uv-in-image-to-xyz-in-pointcloud2-(python)?/) by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2017-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Couldn't find answer anywhere, so I'm sharing my solution. If you have a better option, please post.

This worked for me (using asus Xtion Pro):

```
def pixelTo3DPoint(cloud, u, v):
    width = cloud.width
    height = cloud.height
    point_step = cloud.point_step
    row_step = cloud.row_step

    array_pos = v*row_step + u*point_step

    bytesX = [ord(x) for x in cloud.data[array_pos:array_pos+4]]
    bytesY = [ord(x) for x in cloud.data[array_pos+4: array_pos+8]]
    bytesZ = [ord(x) for x in cloud.data[array_pos+8:array_pos+12]]

    byte_format=struct.pack('4B', *bytesX)
    X = struct.unpack('f', byte_format)[0]

    byte_format=struct.pack('4B', *bytesY)
    Y = struct.unpack('f', byte_format)[0]

    byte_format=struct.pack('4B', *bytesZ)
    Z = struct.unpack('f', byte_format)[0]

    return [X, Y, Z]
```

---

Originally posted by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) with karma: 138 on 2017-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TC](https://answers.ros.org/users/72077/tc/) on 2021-03-17**:
Could you explain further how this works?